# How to add a page with links to collections on shopify

Tags: collections, frameworks, e-commerce, shopify

Hello gius I am setting this e commerce website where i have 15 categories, and I want to make a page where I link all 15 of those as an item or [like that](http://docs.shopify.com/assets/images/support/featuring-collections-3.jpg?1408478111) . I red the tutorial in shopify [click](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/collections/featuring-collections-using-link-lists#Featuring_a_set_of_collections_on_a_regular_page?ref=shopifyninjas) buts its a bit confusing I want to do the same as the 1st part of the tutorial which is add featured collections (as the 1st link), but I want it to be not on the indext page but on a new page let say called "catalog", from there the links to all the 15 categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at this tutorial: [Shopify Theme from Scratch Part 10: list-collections.liquid](http://www.tetchi.ca/shopify-theme-from-scratch-part-10/)

From above turorial:

```
    <h2>Collections</h2>
    {% for collection in collections %}
        <div class="product left {% cycle '','','','last' %}">
          <div class="product-thumb">
            <a href="{{ collection.url  }}">
                {% if collection.image %}
                    {{ collection.image.src | collection_img_url: 'medium' | img_tag: collection_title }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ collection.products.first.featured_image | product_img_url: 'medium' | img_tag: collection_title }}
                {% endif %}              
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="product-title">
            <a href="{{ collection.url}}">
                {{ collection.title }}
              </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks that was one of the tutorials I did not find on goodle, but this worked the trick. :)